# Determining open and closed sets in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

> $\{(x,y):y=nx\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{(x,y):x=0\}$
>
> $\{(x,y):y=qx\text{ for some }q\in\Bbb Q\}\cup\{(x,y):x=0\}$
>
> $\{(x,f(x)):x\in\Bbb R\}$, where $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function

If the above sets are subsets of ${R}^2$, I need to determine whether these sets are open or closed. I'm struggling after proving some relatively easier subsets previously. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? What problem did you encountered when proving this?

Comment: @John Well lets just say I want to just now ask about whether if the first two sets are closed or not, the first one seems to be, so does the second but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: The first one is closed and the second is not. What is the definition of closedness you learnt?

Comment: @John wow thats abit suprising I must be missing something obvious/clever. My defintion is that if we have a sequence in the subset then the limit must also be in the subset.

Comment: Using this definition is good enough, try, for example, to find a sequence of element in the second sets which has limit $(1, \sqrt 2)$.

Comment: @John how would you prove the first one is closed? In regards to the second set, well I just got the sequence I needed and verified its good.

Comment: Hint: You can consider when the limit is not $(0,0)$ because this point is inside the set already. Then $x_n$ must be in some line with slop $k(n)$.